# How to return a file?

Tags: nginx

I had this inside a server block:

```
    if ( $myVar = 1){
        return 200 'abc';
    }
```

Instead of the string, how do I return a file instead?
I tried `return 200 /home/abc.html` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is **return** *code URL*

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return

So you need to use the line like that:

```
if ( $myVar = 1){
    return 200 http://domain.com/abc.html;
}
```